# htaccess redirect website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all my visitors from the old domain that I use to the new one.

Here is the content of the .htaccess file that I use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !foobar.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://foobar.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

where http://foobar.com is the new domain.

The code above works but only if the visitor type http://olddomain.com.

What I mean is when the visitor types

http://olddomain.com/terms.php he should be redirected to http://foobar.com/terms.php

I want that whatever the visitor types after the old domain name (like http://olddomain.com/privacy.php, http://olddomain.com/users.php, etc) they go to 
http://foobar.com/ not to http://foobar.com/privacy.php etc.

Comment: Does it work with other domains? Try e.g. http://google.com/$1

Comment: What do you want exactly, you give two examples, both with different logic.. ? Do you want users to be redirected with full path or only to new domain?

Comment: Is there a proceeding rewrite rule that is being processed first (ie. in the apache config or in a parent folder)?

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^foobar\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://foobar.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```