# I have an absolute url link in a masked url. How can I get it to go to the actual url?

Tags: html, url, href

I have a website that has the url masked as the site itself is hosted away from the registered domain. In it is a link to another site with an absolute url, but when clicked, the url is still the 'masked' url. How can I get it to go to the actual url? The only thing I can think is to use target_blank but I don't want to do that.
Cheers in advance and apologies if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I can't actually see the code you are working with so I'm not positive but have you tried adding `https://` or `http://` to the front of the absolute URL? I find that when it's not included, the link usually doesn't work.

Comment: HI, there is no 'code' other than a link eg- <a href='http ://anotherwebsite.com'>link</a>. And when clicked, the 'masked' url is still in the address bar.

Comment: You need to redirect all URLs in your htaccess file.  Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569183/htaccess-redirect-website

Comment: @SJacks hmm I don't want the website to redirect - I just want a specific link in it to go to the 'actual' url. Are you suggesting I redirect THAT link in htaccess? Cheers

Comment: Yes. htaccess provides the top level of control for URL access. You can redirect one page by using a 301 redirect like this Redirect 301 /oldpage https : // example.com/newpage - take out the spaces after oldpage.

Comment: @SJacks, thanks - I will look at that. You should put this as an answer.